# SSRS - Rename chart label via expressions

Tags: reporting-services, charts, label

Is it possible to use an expression to rename data labels in an SSRS chart?

For instance, if I have axis labels "Domain A" "Domain B" "Domain C", is it possible to rename them to A, B, C?

[sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAorS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Some methods are

1. Add a calculated field to your dataset that contains and expression to do the conversion, then use that calculated field in your chart rather than the original one.
2. Click on the CategoryGroup and in the properties window, change the `Label` property to an expression that does the conversion for you.